# What is the correct approach to using GWT with persistent objects?

Tags: java, design-patterns, gwt, persistence, jdo

I am currently working on a simple web application through Google App engine using GWT. It should be noted that this is my first attempt at such a task.

I have run into to following problem/dilema:

I have a simple Class (getters/setters and nothing more. For the sake of clarity I will refer to this Class as `DataHolder`) and I want to make it persistent. To do so I have used `JDO` which required me to add some annotations and more specifically add a `Key` field to be used as the primary key.

The problem is that using the `Key` class requires me to import `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key` which is ok on the server side, but then I can't use `DataHolder` on the client side, because `GWT` doesn't allow it (as far as I know).

So I have created a sister Class `ClientDataHolder` which is almost identical, though it doesn't have all the `JDO` annotations nor the `Key` field.

Now this actually works but It feels like I'm doing something wrong. Using this approach would require maintaining two separate classes for each entity I wish to have.

So my question is: Is there a better way of doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in thinking that keeping two versions of your objects feels wrong -- the whole idea of GWT is that you can share your server-side objects on the client-side, and if you start divorcing the two you're not taking full advantage of GWT.

As to solving your problem, I've heard nothing but good things about [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/), an alternate API into the datastore that's build just for App Engine.  Among its many advantages, it's also GWT-safe, so you can pass Keys and everything back and forth between client and server.  [Read more here](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/ObjectifyWithGWT).

However, if you want to use JDO/JPA, you can just store your entity IDs as Strings or Longs, like so:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)  
public class SomeDomainClass implements Serializable {  
  @PrimaryKey  
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)  
  @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "gae.encoded-pk", value = "true")  
  String id;
}
```

Read more about that [here](http://blog.sriramnarayan.com/2009/04/gwt-and-jdo-on-java-appengine.html) (which is where I shamelessly stole that code example)

Comment: Thanks.. The String id works great.
I think I'll give Objectify a try because it seems to be exactly what I was looking for.